# Redireccion con tiempo (header)

Tags: php

Hice un condicional que indica si el pago fue aprobado o no y quiero que la pagina se redireccione a otro sitio cuando el pago este aprobado, pero no quiero que sea al instante, quiero que se haga 5 segundos después y no se donde colocar el tiempo.

Dentro del manual de php (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) no veo ejemplos use de tiempo dentro de `header` y vi en otros sitios que se puede agregar `sleep(5);` pero no se si eso esta bien o no.

```
<?php
if($estado == "approved"){
$mensajePaypal = '<h3>Pago aprovado</h3>';

$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET estado = 'approved' WHERE id = '".$idCtm."'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

} else {
$mensajePaypal = '<h3>Hay un problema con el pago de Paypal</h3>';
}

echo $mensajePaypal;
header(location: cuenta.php);
?>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes poner el `sleep(5);` entre el último `echo` y el `header`, ¿qué error te da?

Comment: Lo estaba usando mal. Lo puse dentro del `header`. Perdón, hice toda una pregunta al pedo, soy un inútil. Perdón!

Comment: No, inútil es el que ni lo intenta, ni pide ayuda. Tú has aprendido de tus errores, ¡bien hecho!... La próxima vez déjanos tu código con el error, así será más fácil ayudarte :)

Comment: Muchas gracias David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay un problema:

Los encabezados (header) solo deben enviarse antes de cualquier salida (texto, HTML, un caracter, salto de línea, etc.) y tú ya estás enviando textos. En la mayoría de hosts vas a obtener un mensaje de error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...` y no habrá redirección.

En el mejor de los casos, PHP tiene configurado un buffer que almacena salida hasta llegar a cierta cantidad de caracteres y podrás enviar el encabezado, pero no se van a ver los mensajes previos, porque se quedarán en el buffer y nunca llegarán a la salida.

La opción viable es redireccionar con etiqueta meta, creando la página como lo haces normalmente y esperando el tiempo especificado para ir a la siguiente página:

```
<?php
if($estado == "approved"){
    $mensajePaypal = '<h3>Pago aprovado</h3>';

    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET estado = 'approved' WHERE id = '".$idCtm."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $mensajePaypal = 'Hay un problema con el pago de Paypal';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resultado del pago</title>
<?php 
// Redireccionar solo si el pago fue aplicado
if($estado == 'approved') {
?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=cuenta.php" />
<?php
}  // Endif
?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Resultado del pago</h1>
    <p>$mensajePaypal</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Triby por la info, entonce todos los datos que tengan redirección deben ir antes del HTML?

Comment: Sí, cualquier función que requiera o envíe encabezados (session_start(), setcookie(), header(), etc.) debe usarse sin haber enviado una salida previa.

Comment: Uh... entiendo, bueno, voy a tener que corregir mucho código entonces, mas que nada los ingresos de datos. Pero bueno, gracias nuevamente!